# get users feeds from facebook as rss feeds

Tags: php, facebook, feed

I would like to show my facebook feeds on my website, is there a way to publish our feeds as rss or what other way is possible to achieve the same.

I was looking for something like this- http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/feed though this does not seem to work anymore.

My website is in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook user feeds are accessible in JSON format, so you must only convert `JSON` to `RSS` format.

**EDIT** Now you edited question, and I see that `id/feed` seems to be not available for most of people, but for example here is working one link https://graph.facebook.com/mariusz/feed . I think it is matter of new security facebook policy (try make your wall public for example).

Comment: Try here http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy&ref=mb check "Your status, photos and posts" option for everyone (but I am not sure is it really describes "wall")

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a comprehensive support for feeds, see more [here](http://developers.facebook.com/search?q=Feed)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's feeds are available in RSS 'natively'... Use format http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxx&format=**rss20**. x's are the profile ID you which to have a feed for.